# Variable indirection in ksh

Tags: unix, ksh

In a `ksh`-snippet like the following

```
iname=FA
USER_FA=xyz 
USER_CS=test
TDUSER=USER_$iname
${!TDUSER}
```

`${!TDUSER}` does not work as expected. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `${!var}` works in `bash` but not `ksh93`. Variable indirection in `ksh` uses [`namerefs`](http://oreilly.com/catalog/korn2/chapter/ch04.html#t4):

```
$ iname=FA
$ USER_FA=xyz
$ nameref TDUSER=USER_$iname
$ echo "${TDUSER}"
xyz
```

In `ksh93`, the `!` modifier is used to get the list of indexes from an array: `${!name[@]}` during *parameter substitution*.

Comment: `nameref` is actually an alias for `typeset -n`. The `typeset` built-in command is the Swiss army knife of everything having to do with modifying variable attributes in `ksh93`.